# How to set Tomcat or JBOSS or Glassfish as App-Server for GWT Web Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gwt

How to create and run GWT web project in eclipse with tomcat or another app-server?

I created a Gwt Project and when i run or debug it, eclise did use GWT hosted mode server.
I can not find and configuration in project properties to select tomcat or another server for the project/

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the GWT Run/Debug configuration of the project you want to run/debug, tab Main, deselect the "Run built-in server" option. After that, it's your responsibility to generate the html/js/images of the GWT module you want to run, and place them somewhere where Tomcat or JBoss can see them. That usually means deploying a war at least.

Comment: I don't understand, in netbeans, you create new web project and add gwt frame work to it. then we can select app-server to each project and when we run, it automatically deploy on the server.
How to switch to Tomcat-server for GWT projects?

Comment: Create a static or dynamic web project first, then add the GWT nature to it (right-click, Google->Web Toolkit Settings->Use Web Toolkit).